# Rails 7 failing to import yarn package (https://github.com/keisto/vanilla-rangeslider)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ion-range-slider

This is a non-jQuery version of IonRangeSlider (https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider):

https://github.com/keisto/vanilla-rangeslider

I have used this before by trying to stick to pure JS and avoid adding another layer with JQ.

I installed this via yarn and it's in my node_modules folder.

I added this to my `app/javascript/application.js` file:

```
import IonRangeSlider from 'vanilla-rangeslider/js/rangeslider'
```

after also trying just:

```
import IonRangeSlider from 'vanilla-rangeslider'
```

In my compiled JS file in dev all it has is this:

```
  // ../../node_modules/vanilla-rangeslider/js/rangeslider.js
  var require_rangeslider = __commonJS({
    "../../node_modules/vanilla-rangeslider/js/rangeslider.js"() {
    }
  });
```

and if I try and initialize a slider all I get is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ionRangeSlider is not defined
```

Any ideas here as to what I am missing?  I have added some other yarn based JS package with no issues.

Comment: How come `ionRangeSlider is not defined` has low cap?

Comment: That is how they implement it in the docs `IonRangeSlider` fails also.  The answer below would explain it.

Comment: That's sad in 2022. What you need is referred to as shimming. Bundlers like webpack can provide this option for you, or you can probably download some npm module that provides this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range slider has no exported functions, meaning you won't be able to import anything from it.

The only way to use its functions would be to add it in a `script` tag unfortunately.

Comment: Wondering to myself how hard it would be to fork this and add the export functionality 